# ERR_FAILED (-2) error when running npx cypress open

Tags: electron, cypress

I have a barebone create-react-app with nothing but cypress installed through `npm i cypress`

When I run `npx cypress open` I get this error:

```
 ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'http://localhost:49770/__launchpad/index.html'
Error: ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'http://localhost:49770/__launchpad/index.html'
    at rejectAndCleanup (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:7500)
    at EventEmitter.stopLoadingListener (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:7875)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:domain:475:12)
```

What could be the reason for this? I have tried to stop the firewall and restart my PC but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem with 10.9.0

Comment: Could be related to this github issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/23835

Comment: I have found the issue only occurs with electron, when I run the tests with chrome it's fine. The part giving me trouble is where the page is trying to pop open a new page while redirecting the current to an error page. The link that Michael provided says "we don't support running Cypress commands inside another window (popup or new tab)", so this seems consistent, though it is a different error than described here.

Answer (score 3):

https://lightrun.com/answers/cypress-io-cypress-1030-regression---test-runner-randomly-fails-when-running-electron-locally

I found a solution that worked for me. I was running the command in a cmd with admin privileges. According to this article, you need to run it in a cmd without admin rights.